# Why is this Sidekiq fake test not increasing the size of the jobs array?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sidekiq, airbrake

I have the following test setup for a sidekiq test using the fake testing in https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing.

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.fake!

# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryGirl.reload
    FactoryGirl.define do
      to_create { |instance| instance.save }
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    Airbrake.configure do |c|
      c.project_id = ENV['AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_ID']
      c.project_key = ENV['AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_KEY']
    end
  end

  config.before(:each, job: true) do
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all #make sure jobs don't linger between tests
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

**notification_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe NotificationWorker do
  it "perform should call Airbrake#notify", job: true do
    notification_worker = NotificationWorker.new
    message = "This is your error message"
    expect { notification_worker.perform(message) }.to change(NotificationWorker.jobs, :size).by(1)
  end
end
```

**notification_worker.rb**

```
class NotificationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :high

  def perform(message)
    Airbrake.notify(message)
  end
end
```

Yet, why do I receive the following error message:

```
Failure/Error: expect { notification_worker.perform(message) }.to change(NotificationWorker.jobs, :size).by(1)
       expected #size to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

It seems as if the jobs array should be incremented by 1.  What is going on?  Is it a threading issue caused by the interaction between RSpec and Database Cleaner?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's calling the perform method directly and not Sidekiq's API.

Try `NotificationWorker.perform_async(message)`

Comment: So that is by design then?  You wouldn't want to stub out the perform method in a fake test?

Comment: Calling `perform` directly will not queue a job whether in a test or in production.  It's just a method call and will run immediately.  `perform_async` will queue a job. When a worker picks up that job from the queue it will run the `perform` method.